# How to publish special Char(",\) message to PubNub?

Tags: android, push-notification, encode, publish-subscribe, pubnub

I 'm developing an android app. Integrating PubNub with our app for Push Notifications.

I'm getting error while Publishing an message to PubNub using PubNub Api method called Publish.

I'm getting error especially while publishing the below two special characters.

> "
>
> \

Comment: Could you share any more information about the error? Also share your code for publishing if you could. This could be incorrect message syntax. A safe way of sending data is putting it all in a JSONObject and sending that.

Comment: Yes I have fixed it by encoding and decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding/Decoding is correct, but also, be sure you do not send JSON content as a string. Always [send a JSON object](http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/495/can-i-send-and-or-receive-json-objects) if the content **is** JSON data.